# Replace all "&gt;"(>) which are inside <code> tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I replace all `&gt;` with `>` and `&lt;` with `<` inside a `<code>` tag with ruby?

For example:

```
<code>&lt;script&gt;`alert('I steal cookies');`&lt;/script&gt;</code>
```

With:

```
<code><script>alert('I steal cookies);<script><code>
```

The reason for this is because the `h()` method escapes all the `< and >`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason for this is because the h() method escapes all the `<`  and `>`

The method works correctly, the tags *should* be escaped. Why do you want to unescape them?

If you don’t want to escape the output (because you actually want to output tags), simply don’t call `h()`.

If you don’t have control over the calling of `h()`, then you may mark your string as “HTML safe” by calling the appropriate method on your string before passing it to `h()`. But it’s really hard to say if that’s appropriate for you:

```
s = "<strong>example</strong>".html_safe
h(s) # = "<strong>example</strong>"
```

Or:

```
s = "<strong>example</strong>"
s.html_safe!
h(s) # = "<strong>example</strong>"
```

Comment: I'm using maruku to enable markdown.
And i don't want to escape tags inside of a `<code>` tag because if i fo that the browser outputs `&gt;` and `&lt;` insteade of `<>`.

Comment: @Micke: No, the browser does **not** do that. Definitely. If that happens, you’re escaping twice. My guess is that maruku is automatically escaping code inside `<code>` tags so you mustn’t do that yourself.

Comment: yeah, my bad. You are right. but Maruku doesnt escape the other text outside the code tag:(